# Method that converts a datatype

Tags: ruby, variables

I am looking for a method that converts the receiver into a string. In the following, `a.to_s` does not alter the referent of `a`. `a` returns `3`.

```
a = 3
a.to_s #=> "3"
a #=> 3
```

I want something like

```
a = 3
a.some_method
a #=> "3"
```

`a` should return `"3"`.

Answer (score 3):

Just assign the string.

```
a = 3
a = a.to_s
```

Or more succinctly...

```
a = 3.to_s
```

Some objects are mutable and some are immutable, but there is no mechanism where you can make `3.some_method` change the data_type (class) of an object.

The above solution simply assigns a new object of the desired data_type to the variable.

And variables are very "dumb" referrers and don't have methods themselves, doing `a.some_method` is calling `#some_method` on the referred object (`3.some_method`).

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP was asking. And mutability is irrelevant. You cannot change the referent of a variable between Fixnum and String.

Comment: @sawa you're right I'll edit when I'm back in my chair

Comment: I need one single method to update change data type without assignment to itself.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that.  An object's data type is immutable, so an integer stays an integer.  You would need to do another assignment so that the variable points to a different object of the correct type.

The only thing I can suggest is that all references to `a` (barring the assignments) you change it to `a.to_s`

Answer (score 2):

That is impossible. Whatever object a method returns, it does not change the referent of a variable that refers to that receiver.